# wrong # args: should be "foreach varList list ?varList list ...? command"

Tags: for-loop, expect

this is the .txt file

```
desk-12
desk-123
desk-auto-1234
```

this is the .expect file

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set f [open "listOfIps.txt"]
set ips [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f

set PASSWORD "test@123"
puts "$ips"

   foreach HOST $ips{

    expect -> "
    puts $HOST
    #spawn scp -r /usr/bin/scp /Users/test-123/1.png admin@$HOST:/home/testFolder
    expect {
    "*password:*"
    { send $PASSWORD\r}
     }
               }
    puts "completed"
```

can anyone help me how to solve this "wrong # args: should be "foreach varList list ?varList list ...? command"" error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the line

```
foreach HOST $ips{
```

you need to add a space between `$ips` and `{` for Tcl to parse this correctly.